# HTML to PDF conversion using scala - Need alternate way of approach

Tags: java, html, scala, pdf

I am using the following code to convert my HTML From .html File to PDF File.
This Works properly and converted to PDF File as expected.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.net.URL
import javax.imageio.ImageIO
import java.io
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;
object Hello{
    def main(args: Array[String]) { 
    var fos: FileOutputStream = null
    val File_To_Convert  ="F:/Pdf_Generation/Appointment Schedule_Fair_Edit.html";
    val url = new File(File_To_Convert).toURI().toURL().toString();
    val HTML_TO_PDF = "F:/Pdf_Generation/fffkflfkldjklja.pdf";
    fos = new FileOutputStream(HTML_TO_PDF);
    val renderer =new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocument(url);     
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(fos);  
    fos.close();    
    }
}
```

But Instead of sending the PDF file, I need to send the raw in " var File_To_Convert". If i Do that then it shows stream closed error. But if i send the HTML file it converts as expected but it does not work when i am sending the raw html. Please suggest how to solve this.

Thanks in Advance.